# How i can compare 2 arrays with dates and get period of unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays with datas:

1) Array with dates booked

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2019-01-30
                [check_in] => 2019-01-28
                [check_out] => 2019-02-02
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2019-01-31
                [check_in] => 2019-01-28
                [check_out] => 2019-02-02
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2019-02-01
                [check_in] => 2019-01-28
                [check_out] => 2019-02-02
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2019-02-05
                [check_in] => 2019-02-05
                [check_out] => 2019-02-06
            )

    )
```

2) Array of dates beetween 2 dates, it's next 10 days after today.

```
Array
(

    [0] => 2019-01-30

    [1] => 2019-01-31

    [2] => 2019-02-01

    [3] => 2019-02-02

    [4] => 2019-02-03

    [5] => 2019-02-04

    [6] => 2019-02-05

    [7] => 2019-02-06

    [8] => 2019-02-07

    [9] => 2019-02-08

)
```

How i can get one first period of available dates, to make discount for this dates, i guess i need do recursive foreach, but maybe someone will give good tip how to do it more quality code.
In this example i need get:

Array
    (

```
    [0] => 2019-02-02

    [1] => 2019-02-03

    [2] => 2019-03-04

)
```

UPD Find the short way to get Array of free dates:

```
            $arr = []; \\days of available with same format

            foreach ($array as $key => $item) { //$array array of busy days
                $arr[] = $item["date"];
            }
            $datesArray = $arrayAllDays; //$arrayAllDays array next 10 days 

            $arr2 = array_diff($datesArray, $arr); //when I got 2 array with same format I can compare 2 array.
```

Outpoot:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 2019-02-02
    [4] => 2019-02-03
    [5] => 2019-02-04
    [7] => 2019-02-06
    [8] => 2019-02-07
    [9] => 2019-02-08
)
```

So keys now is (missing 0,1,2 cos booked),3,4,5 (missing 6 cos booked) etc.

So i need get now value of **3, 4, 5**, how do it?

Comment: Can you modify the format of the data, specifically remove the "-" characters and turn each date entry into an int? If so, you may just be able to build a loop of arithmetic checks for each of your "candidate dates," and if the candidate date does not fall within the range of one of your bookings, you can list it as available.

Answer (score 1):

Here is *one* way:

```
// Assumes given dates are valid
function getAvailableDays($startDate, $endDate, $reservations, $dayInSeconds = 86400)
{
    // Lets create a range of integers that represent each date
    $availableTimestamps = range(
        date_create($startDate)->getTimestamp(),
        date_create($endDate)->getTimestamp(),
        $dayInSeconds
    );

    foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
        // Similar to above, create a range for each reservation's check-in/check-out
        $reservedTimestamps = range(
            date_create($reservation['check_in'])->getTimestamp(),
            date_create($reservation['check_out'])->getTimestamp(),
            $dayInSeconds
        );

        // ..And here is where the magic happens
        // By using array_diff, we'll continuously remove reserved
        // data points from the available data points
        $availableTimestamps = array_diff($availableTimestamps, $reservedTimestamps);
    }

    // Return the result as an array of available dates in format like: 2019-01-31
    return array_map(function ($timestamp) {
        return date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
    }, $availableTimestamps);
}
```

---

**Suppose we have the following input data:**

```
$startDate = '2019-01-31';
$endDate   = '2019-02-09';

$reservations = [
    [
        'date'      => '2019-01-28',
        'check_in'  => '2019-01-28',
        'check_out' => '2019-02-02'
    ],

    [
        'date'      => '2019-02-05',
        'check_in'  => '2019-02-05',
        'check_out' => '2019-02-06'
    ]
];
```

**Here is what the output would be:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 2019-02-03
    [4] => 2019-02-04
    [7] => 2019-02-07
    [8] => 2019-02-08
    [9] => 2019-02-09
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$next_10 = 
[
  '2019-01-30'.
  '2019-01-31',
  '2019-02-01',
  '2019-02-02',
  '2019-02-03',
  '2019-02-04',
  '2019-02-05',
  '2019-02-06',
  '2019-02-07',
  '2019-02-08',
];

$reserved = [
  [
    'date' => '2019-01-30',
    'check_in' => '2019-01-28',
    'check_out' => '2019-02-02'
  ],
  [
    'date' => '2019-01-31',
    'check_in' => '2019-01-28',
    'check_out' => '2019-02-02'
  ],
  [
    'date' => '2019-02-01',
    'check_in' => '2019-01-28',
    'check_out' => '2019-02-02'
  ],
  [
    'date' => '2019-02-05',
    'check_in' => '2019-02-05',
    'check_out' => '2019-02-06'
  ]
];

$available = array(); // will contain the available dates
foreach($next_10 as $day) // we check each of the next 10 days
{
  $free = TRUE; // we assume the date is available unless we prove it is not
  foreach($reserved as $res) // loop through each booking
  {
    if($day >= $res['check_in'] AND $day < $res['check_out'])
    {
      // this date is already booked
      $free = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
  if($free) $available[] = $day; // this date was really not booked
  if(count($available) == 3) break;
}

var_dump($available);
```

When you run the code above it will produce the following output

[image]

Comment: It's good option to do that, i found almoust same, but your script return $key like 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7

Using this key i can get 2 and 3 key and make discount from 2 => value to 3 => value and than break loop for this listing.

Comment: I really do not get your point. There is no variable named `$key` in the code. Perhaps you can try to explain in Russian?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i just print some variables in same page to find best solution, i mean Keys in array. And your function print me 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc.

My function print 0,1,2,3,7,8 so maybe its good idea use Keys to find period that more than 1.

I UPD head question and found little different solution, but cannot do first task, how i can get only first free period, and than break loop.

Comment: I have added sample input data to confirm that the output is what you need

Comment: But if dates will change and count of available days will change. If we have 10 days, next 3 days are busy, from 4 to 7 days is free and 8 day is busy, function will show 2 period available: 1 period (from 4 to 7 and from 9 to 10)  I need just one from 4 to 7. It can be any dates, it can be 3 period and 5 period.